# How does std::reverse_iterator hold one before begin?

Tags: c++, iterator, reverse-iterator

This is a code example using `std::reverse_iterator`:

```
template<typename T, size_t SIZE>
class Stack {
    T arr[SIZE];
    size_t pos = 0;
public:
    T pop() {
        return arr[--pos];
    }
    Stack& push(const T& t) {
        arr[pos++] = t;
        return *this;
    }
    auto begin() {
        return std::reverse_iterator(arr+pos);
    }
    auto end() {
        return std::reverse_iterator(arr);
                // ^ does reverse_iterator take this `one back`? how?
    }
};

int main() {
    Stack<int, 4> s;
    s.push(5).push(15).push(25).push(35);
    for(int val: s) {
        std::cout << val << ' ';
    }
}

// output is as expected: 35 25 15 5
```

---

When using `std::reverse_iterator` as an adaptor for another iterator, the newly adapted *end* shall be one before the original *begin*. However calling `std::prev` on *begin* is UB.

How does `std::reverse_iterator` hold one before begin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialization of `std::reverse_iterator` from an iterator does not decrease the iterator upon initialization, as it would then be UB when sending *begin* to it (one cannot assume that `std::prev(begin)` is a valid call).

The trick is simple, `std::reverse_iterator` holds the original iterator passed to it, without modifying it. Only when it is being dereferenced it peeks back to the actual value. So in a way the iterator is pointing inside to the *next* element, from which it can get the current.

It would look something like:

```
// partial possible implementation of reverse_iterator for demo purpose
template<typename Itr>
class reverse_iterator {
    Itr itr;
public:
    constexpr explicit reverse_iterator(Itr itr): itr(itr) {}

    constexpr auto& operator*() {
        return *std::prev(itr); // <== only here we peek back
    }
    constexpr auto& operator++() {
        --itr;
        return *this;
    }
    friend bool operator!=(reverse_iterator<Itr> a, reverse_iterator<Itr> b) {
        return a.itr != b.itr;
    }
};
```

This is however an internal implementation detail (and can be in fact implemented in other similar manners). The user of `std::reverse_iterator` shall not be concerned with how it is implemented.